# How to add sitemap xml file in drupal

Tags: php, xml, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I am currently working in a Drupal project and as i am new to Drupal, so i am not able to figure out how to add a sitemap(xml file) in Drupal.
I searched online but could not find any solutions
Kindly help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about Drupal site administration and may better fit  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way would be to use the [xmlsitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module.

This will allow you to fine tune inclusion and exclusion rules for each of your content types as well as apply an importance weight to them.